# More In Cylinder Pressure Testing Questions

Tags: diagnostics, compression, combustion-cycle, four-stroke, compression-testing

So I was looking at a 06 Pontiac G6 2.4l with a complaint of low power on hills. Had been at another shop to have the transmission checked and they referred the customer to us.

Road test confirms car doesn't go anywhere fast.

I didn't really think this through when I was taking captures and failed to get a longer zoomed out view on cylinder 1, the ignition timing mark, was short on time etc...

---

All captures are in Park. Using a Snap-on EEPV302AT 500 PSI pressure transducer.

Cylinder 1 running compression idle to WOT:

[image]

The end of the exhaust valve event where the intake valve opens looks weird.

Zoomed in:

[image]

It doesn't look right but what do I know?

So onto cylinder two...

Cranking compression @ WOT:

[image]

OK... how about running compression?

Cylinder 2 idle to 3000 RPM to WOT zoomed out:

[image]

Let's zoom in a little...

[image]

Still seeing a pressure spike at the end of the exhaust stroke.

Zoomed in on the WOT portion:

[image]

Zoomed in at idle:

[image]

---

At this point I ran out of time and had to pack up. I plan on taking more captures on Monday with the B1S1 O2S removed. And confirming exhaust backpressure with a transducer in the o2 bung.

So, in pictures 1, 2, 5, and 7 what exactly is happening when the intake valve is opening and the exhaust valve is closing? Is this because since both valves are open and the piston is at TDC, it's sucking more air out of the intake manifold and results in the pressure spike due to the exhaust being potentially plugged?

In picture 6 this is kind of what I expected to see with a plugged exhaust. Would there be another explanation for the pressure spike?

In pictures 3 and 7 why are the exhaust and intake events almost the same? It looks like it's slowly building pressure.

---

**Update**

Confirmed exhaust backpressure with a gauge, around 3 PSI @ idle and 8 PSI @ 3000 RPM.

Did another in cylinder capture on cylinder 2. Even with the o2 sensor removed the waveform was similar to picture 6. Very puzzling.

After repair @ 3000 RPM

[image]

Bonus picture off a Mini

[image]

Comment: Must_Own a EEPV302AT some day.  But where does the transducer go for individual cylinder measurements?  O2 bungs I get, but is there a spark plug feed through or something?  How (more importantly physically *where*) does it measure cylinder pressure on a individual cylinder from idle to WOT?

Comment: @SteveRacer It's all through the plug well you're basically doing a compression test, but on a scope. Ground the coil/wire unplug the injector etc...

Comment: Thanks.  Got it.  Seems to be huge cylinder to cylinder differences, yet your blocked exhaust theory better explains the odd transition shape to the next cycle.  So B1S1 is the *only× " bank " on this ecotech? Doesn't play well together

Comment: @SteveRacer Yes The Ecotec 2.4 is a single bank. No split manifold or anything like that. The differences cylinder to cylinder do make me wonder. The cylinder captures on 2 were a bit more thorough though.

Comment: And this is a chain too, correct?  Nothing that jumped a tooth without shrapnel...(sorry I'm not a GM guy)

Comment: @SteveRacer Yup chain. mileage is only around 40k. no noise from the engine. i may do a cam crank correlation. but as i understand you can gauge cam timing by looking at the compression waveform. Peak to peak is 720 degrees if you divide that into quarters you have each stroke. if the 180 degree line is shifted to the left or right. this normally falls on the exhaust valve slope. than cam timing is off.

Comment: Chain would not have caused differences in inter-cylinder pressure anyway.  Broken valve spring, pitted cam? ...  My guessing is probably not even useful as your own.  Awesome tool, however.  I promise to lurk (much to your chagrin) until there's more data.

Comment: Have you checked valve clearances? It suggests to me that the exhaust valve is slow to open. If it was all cylinders then id supect timing. If its only one then could it be huge clearance delaying opening and/or closing early?

Comment: @Peter No never checked valve clearance. The convertor was restricted enough for the power complaint. After R&R car drove fine. I did another in cylinder test and the results look much the same. I'll dig out the vsm file and post some frames later. I'm suspecting the bump is due to the variable valve timing on the cams. I don't have to car anymore to correlate with actuator position.

Comment: Is it just possible that what you're seeing is just normal phenomenon? As the revs increase the as the engine does its exhaust stroke there is a slight lag before the gasses make thier way to exit. Do you see the same behavior on other engines. Even better can you do the same test on another vehicle with a similar engine?

Comment: @Peter I think this may just be normal, I'll run a test on my own car tomorrow it's not a GM 2.4 but it is a 4 cylinder DOHC with variable valve timing on both cams.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @Peter actually I did. I did some searching on IATN and found known good pressure waveforms.  It turns out that hump is completely normal. I'll throw an answer up pater tonight when i have some more time.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching on IATN and found known good pressure waveforms that are identical to my after repair captures. Unfortunately I can't post them here. It turns out that hump is completely normal.

After doing more captures on different cars with VVT I've found that most waveforms are unique to some degree. I guess the same can be said about non VVT engines based on the camshaft profile. Though they do look pretty similar.